# Angular Matarial toolbar icons are not formatted

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added `@angular/material` to ng app via `ng add @angular/material`. Then I imported my Modules in `app.modules.ts` as you can see here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my `AppComponent` I've copied this code from material.angular.io for the Toolbar:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>
    Test
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <button mat-button>
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>My App</span>
      
    </mat-toolbar>
    
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

But the result now looks wrong. Has anybody any idea why the buttons are displayed wrong formatted?

[image: Strange looking toolbar]

Comment: Did you re-serve the application, as `@angular/material` edit your `angular.json` file to add material styles ?
Just try re-serving your app.

Comment: I think you're missing `MatButtonModule`, since you are referring to it: `<button mat-button>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `MatButtonModule` to your imports list in `AppModule`.

Should look like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from "@angular/material/sidenav";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

/* Added this import */
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,

    /* Added this import */
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```